# What is this C# code usage concept called? And how does it work?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I was looking at an MSDN about `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitortimercallback(v=vs.110).aspx) and found this usage in the example -

```
    ti.Handle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
            ev,
            new WaitOrTimerCallback(WaitProc),
            ti,
            1000,
            false
        );
```

Where `WaitProc` is a method -

```
    public static void WaitProc(object state, bool timedOut)
    {
     //Code
    }
```

I also found examples where the same by replacing `WaitProc` method to something similar to this -

```
    ti.Handle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
            ev,
            (state, timedOut) => {
            //code blah blah
            //manipulate state
            //manipulate timedOut
            }
            ti,
            1000,
            false
        );
```

Here I'm assuming the method `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` expects a `WaitOrTimerCallback` method, and compiler understand this and considers `(state, timedOut)` as the method, and hence the variables can be used within the call itself.

What is this concept called?

And how does it work?

Comment: This is called a [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: its called lambda expression,and if you are new to it you probably should check anonymous methods first to get a good grasp of the syntax then check lambdas

Answer (score 4):

> What is this concept called?
>
> And how does it work?

It is called a [Lambda Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). The compiler takes the expression and translates it into a named method for you, while saving you the trouble of actually defining a named method that matches the delegates signature each time.

Using [TryRoslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoUlaIoYB0AKgBYBOqAhgCb44AOwARgDZgDGMX7NIEDADCMAN7YYUmCw7cYANwD2YOjACyACgCU4ydIMKalGKgUwAvDAioA7huBoAHjpwHDxmDUswK1egAKSkrsxABKqFBgRJQA6jRgyABiSpRw+OyoAPKsAFaoXMia+u7uZgA0JaXSmig0aOUwyGDoqHRZjroWAHx61e4A9ANcSnSoMBw05BP85FX9Q+g0EGAs/GgwdWjz1YvLq8Dr482t7Y47pQC+lf0GEIfsN7dSAIwADB9PzwBmNOwgqAuMG0bmkl2wlyAA), this is what your delegate compiles down to (on the new Roslyn compiler):

```
private sealed class <>c
{
    public static readonly C.<>c <>9;
    public static WaitOrTimerCallback <>9__0_0;
    static <>c()
    {
        // Note: this type is marked as 'beforefieldinit'.
        C.<>c.<>9 = new C.<>c();
    }
    internal void <M>b__0_0(object state, bool timedOut)
    {
    }
}

public void M()
{
    Mutex mutex = new Mutex();
    WaitHandle arg_2E_0 = mutex;
    WaitOrTimerCallback arg_2E_1;
    if (arg_2E_1 = C.<>c.<>9__0_0 == null)
    {
        arg_2E_1 = C.<>c.<>9__0_0 = new WaitOrTimerCallback(C.<>c.<>9.<M>b__0_0);
    }
    RegisteredWaitHandle registeredWaitHandle = 
        ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(arg_2E_0, arg_2E_1, null, 1000, false);
}
```